# VB6 to connect to sybase 16 with charset = big5

Tags: vb6, sybase, ado

I used VB6 ADO version 2.7 to connect to sybase 16 using sybase native driver to retrieve some Chinese Character in the database.  I included `charset=big5` in the connection string. However, I still got some messy string instead of Chinese character.

I tried to use a database tool which uses JDBC to connect to the database without any issue if I configure the charset to `big5`. What's the problem using ADO with native driver? The ADO connection doesn't support the charset property?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some minimal code that reproduces the issue?